# How to delete Chax from Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ichat

How do I remove Chax? I only want iChat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean the iChat-Addon [Chax](http://www.ksuther.com/chax/), according to its website:

> **Removing Chax**
>   There are two ways to remove Chax. The quickest way is to **run the Chax installer and select "Remove"**. To manually remove Chax, open `~/Library/ScriptingAdditions` (~ indicates your home folder) and move `ChaxAddition.osax` to the trash. After logging out and back in, empty the trash.

Comment: Check the deleted answers below, maybe you can expand your answer to include possible fixes for that too? Seems like a popular question…